# Can a Origami shape be mathematically defined?

Tags: origami

Given any origami shape, Can It be mathematically defined say any function or equation that can satisfy all points of the origami shape ?

If so, How such functions for any origami can be derived with some general steps ?

Comment: This question is quite unclear, but there is a lot of mathematics about origami, see here for example: http://erikdemaine.org/folding/

Comment: Origamis are very mathematical. MIT even has an open course ware course on them: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-849-geometric-folding-algorithms-linkages-origami-polyhedra-fall-2012/index.htm It has lecture videos, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you identify a point on the piece of paper you start with as a triple of coordinates (when you start folding paper, the thickness quickly becomes a factor, so I think you need to take the third dimension in account) and place the resulting shape in a coordinate system, it's obvious that you can then define a function mapping any point in the paper with the corresponding point in the resulting shape.

I'm not good at (not even particularly interested in) origami, but if you have a description of how to come from a piece of paper, containing *all* (including lifting, turning etc.) the transformations you should do to the piece of paper, I can't see a (theoretical) problem in using those on the coordinates to find a function, but I don't see use. And going the opposite way seems hard.